# Simulation problem

Tags: rigid-body-simulation

I am trying achieve a simple falling mesh on a plane, but when I start the simulation goes well until a certain frame where meshes seems "attracted" by something. My simulation solvers are in mesh, I've applied every transformsand modifiers, and it worked well with a cube. I deleted the rigod body world a bunch of time, I've try to import it in another scene, I've tried to delete every other meshes, I've try to increase the substeps AND the solver iterations, it still doesn't work. There is 2 planes because I've tried to create another plane from scratch to see if it changes something but it don't, the first work the same way as the second. Also, the solver for the table is convex hull, I've tried with the box solver but the meshes simply goes trough the cube.
[Here is my parameters and the behavior in a video (click on the link)](https://youtu.be/wpU-Us7Pmy8)

Comment: Hi. Please use a title that matches the content of the question. It should be descriptive but succinct, unique and identifying, summarizing the issue in such way that anyone searching for a similar problem is likely to find it. Use the [edit] link above, remove anything superfluous, avoid words like "*this*", "*help*", "*issue with*" or "*question about*". Remember, your title is the first thing potential visitors see, answers you get depend heavily on how insightful it is. See [*What is the problem of asking “How do I do this?"*](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2449)

Comment: Hello and welcome. While files, images, and external videos or links may be helpful additions they should not be the only way to obtain information about your issue. Don't make understanding your question rely on downloading a file, watching a video or visiting an external site. Use the builtin tools to upload [images](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491) or [gifs](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/963), along with thoroughly explaining the problem in written form so it can be indexed and searched for thus helping future visitors with similar issues.

Comment: If you share the blend file - I might be able to help.
Looks like either its retaining some old cache. Try deleting the sim cache, make a small change and re-sim.
See if you have any hidden objects? or Forces.

Comment: Hello, thanks for your help. I already tried to delete the cache (I'm not sure I did it right but I think). There is no other objects, I deleted everything, and I never used a force so maybe there is one hidden but I don't really know how it works.

Comment: here is the blend file : https://we.tl/t-cAuBlDFBIw

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like it's a problem with the spheres origin position, select all your objects and right click > *Set Origin > Origin to Geometry*. Also apply the scales of your objects.

Comment: THANKS A LOT YOU'RE RIGHT !! I complitely forget to reset the origin haha my bad